# PHP how to stop a submit button in a form

Tags: php

I have a database with different activities, their dates and descriptions and I am doing a table with it that looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzyg9.png)

So basically, when someone use the submit button their user id (id_user), the id of the activity (id_f) and the maximum number of people in an activity (nb_max) is sent to my database named 'atelier'.

It works but it doesn't stop when the button is pushed, for instance the user is registering to all of the activities at once (I only want him to be registered to the activity where the submit button is) ! There is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp2zj.png) of my database 'atelier' after submitting the button.

Here is my html/php code :

```
<thead>
    <tr> 
        <!-- Creating the title of my table -->
        <th>Date de la formation</th>
        <th>Debut</th>
        <th>Fin</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Nombre maximum de participants</th>
        <th>Créateur</th>
        <th>État</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php
// $contenu = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM formation ORDER BY date_f');

// Creating the row of my table
while ($donnees = $contenu->fetch()) 
{
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['date_f']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['h_debut']; ?>h</td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['h_fin']; ?>h</td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['contenu']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['nb_max']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['id_user']; ?></td>
    <td>
    <?php 
        $id_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];
        $id_f = $donnees['id_f'];
        $nb_max = $donnees['nb_max'];

        // Checking if the user has already registered to the activity
        $reqAtelier = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM atelier WHERE id_user = ? AND id_f = ?"); 
        $reqAtelier->execute(array($id_user, $id_f));
        $atelierExist = $reqAtelier->rowCount();

            // If not, he can register like so
            if($atelierExist == 0) {
                if(isset($_POST['forminscription'])) {   
                    $insertmbr = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO atelier (id_f, nb_max, id_user) VALUES(?, ?, ?)" );
                    $insertmbr->execute(array($id_f, $nb_max, $id_user));
                    header("LOCATION: activites.php"); // Refreshing the page after sending the information 
                } 
            ?>
            <form method="POST" action="activites.php">
                <input type="submit" name="forminscription" value="Register" />
            </form> 
            <?php
                }
            // Otherwise, the submit button changes value and doesn't do anything
            // This works fine since after pushing my submit button once, all of the button turn to 'Already registered'
            else{
                ?>
            <form method="POST" action="activites.php">
                <input type="submit" name="forminscription" value="Already registered" />
            </form> 
            <?php
            }

    ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

I am using fetch() to create my table and I think that is why I am getting all of the activities at once. But I can't exit my while statement, so this is why I am trying to exit my if statement or to stop my button from working.

Do you know how can I fix my problem and only get the values of the activity where my submit button is ?
Is there a solution to do this without using javascript ?

I tried to be as clear as possible, so I hope you'll understand my problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Add hidden field(s) to these forms that transport whatever info you actually need on the receiving end.

Comment: you seem to be running a loop which does an INSERT into the activities table, regardless of what the user has submitted. Try actually looking at the posted data - you seem to be basing your inserts on a list of all possible activities, rather than anything the user chose. Right now, your form doesn't even contain a field to indicate which activity was selected! As misorude says, you need to set a hidden field containing the relevant activity ID. And if the user is already registered, don't give them any "submit" buttons at all - just a plain-text message would be better.

Comment: In short, the inserting of the records should be a separate process, outside your while loop. The while loop's primary purpose seems to be displaying the current data. But you're mixing a second purpose into it - the inserting - which should be happening at a separate time and in separate code. Don't mangle two unrelated pieces of functionality together in this way.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson, splitting the loop's function is much more clear now ! And for the second submit button, it's primary purpose was to enable the user to unregister to the activity (but to clarify my code I kept it with just a single value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your insertion code is inside a loop, that's why you get multiple rows inserted. What you want to do instead is sending more parameters in your form.

```
<?php
$id_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];

$result = $bdd->prepare("SELECT id_f FROM atelier WHERE id_user = ? GROUP BY id_f"); 
$result->execute(array($id_user));
$userActivities = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);


if(isset($_POST['id_f'], $_POST['nb_max'])) {
    $id_f = $_POST['id_f'];
    $nb_max = $_POST['nb_max'];

    // Checking if the user has already registered to the activity
    // If not, he can register like so
    if(!in_array($id_f, $userActivities)) {   
        $insertmbr = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO atelier (id_f, nb_max, id_user) VALUES(?, ?, ?)" );
        if ($insertmbr->execute(array($id_f, $nb_max, $id_user))) {
            $userActivities[] = $id_f;
        }
        // No need to refresh the page, since we insert first then we fetch
    } 
}
?>
<thead>
    <tr> 
        <!-- Creating the title of my table -->
        <th>Date de la formation</th>
        <th>Debut</th>
        <th>Fin</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Nombre maximum de participants</th>
        <th>Créateur</th>
        <th>État</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php
// $contenu = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM formation ORDER BY date_f');

// Creating the row of my table
while ($donnees = $contenu->fetch()) 
{
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['date_f']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['h_debut']; ?>h</td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['h_fin']; ?>h</td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['contenu']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['nb_max']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $donnees['id_user']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <?php if (!in_array($donnees['id_f'], $userActivities)): ?>
        <form method="POST" action="activites.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="id_f" value="<?php echo $donnees['id_f']; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="nb_max" value="<?php echo $donnees['nb_max']; ?>" />
            <input type="submit" name="forminscription" value="Register" />
        </form> 
        <?php else: ?>
        <p>Already registered</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I changed your code a bit. First, I get all of the user's activities. I did that because you don't want to have a query inside a loop, that's bad performance. Then inside the loop and on the insertion I check if the user has the activity simply by checking if it's in the array.

Note: For the sake of simplicity I went with array of values. Better performance will be with some kind of a hash-table, and check with `isset()` instead of `in_array()`.

Example:

```
$userActivitiesHash = array_flip($userActivities);
```

Then:

```
isset($userActivitiesHash[$id_f])
```

And:

```
!isset($userActivitiesHash[$donnees['id_f']])
```

Comment: The only things I'd improve on this is to move the first $bdd->prepare inside the `if` - because you only need to run that if you need to check whether the user already registered a specific activity and is trying to register again. And secondly I think there is no need to refresh the page again - instead just let it continue executing - it will run a new SELECT query, and show all the current status for the activities, including the one which was just updated, and return it direct to the user without any further HTTP requests.

Comment: @ADyson You are correct about the refresh. About the first query, I need it also for the display part (when not submitting) because OP wants a different form displayed.

Comment: Good point. You know you could also consider not actually providing a user with a form, if they are already registered for an activity. Since they are not allowed to register again, they would seem to have no need to submit any more data. A simple piece of read-only text would do instead. Then there's no confusion about pressing submit again.

Comment: @ADyson That's a good point, I'll leave it to OP to decide since that's his original code.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, it helped a lot ! @HTMHell you code works fine and I can send the value I want to my database but I am having an issue with it. I think it is the if statement in the while loop, because after registering, the submit button's value doesn't change and also, I can send values to my DB multiple times. I am going to dig up the solution with the hash-table to see if it works better!